# Which library implements AdaBoost.NC?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, boosting, ensemble-learning

The [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html) implementation of `AdaBoost` uses the [AdaBoost.SAMME](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/15a949460/sklearn/ensemble/_weight_boosting.py#L285) variant of the algorithm. Is there a known python-based library the uses the `AdaBoost.NC` variant as proposed in [AdaBoost.NC](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5596702)?

Comment: I have no experience with the package, but perhaps [`PyRidge`](https://github.com/cperales/pyridge) could help?